# I'm trying display severeal lines from a database in NetBeans, but only one line appears

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I'm currently having to do a code where, when ran, connects to a database and displays all the grades of a student after putting in their appropriate SSN. The main obstacle I'm running into is that once I put in the SSN it'll only bring one of the grades rather than all. Is there something wrong with my logic? Am I just utilizing incorrect parts to do this? I've tried putting more than one lblstatus but that didn't work. Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.*;

public class Week13 extends Application {

    private TextField tfSSN = new TextField();
    private Label lblStatus = new Label();
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        initializeDB();

        Button btShowGrade = new Button("Show Grade");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("SSN"), tfSSN, (btShowGrade));

        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox, lblStatus);

        tfSSN.setPrefColumnCount(6);
        btShowGrade.setOnAction(e -> showGrade());

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 420, 80);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FindGrade"); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.show(); 
    }

    private void initializeDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("blank for the purpose of posting this");
            System.out.println("Database connected");
            String queryString = "select firstName, mi, lastName, title, grade " 
                + "from Student, Enrollment, Course where Student.ssn = ? and "
                + "Enrollment.ssn = Student.ssn and Enrollment.courseId = "
                + "Course.courseId";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void showGrade() { 
      String ssn = tfSSN.getText();

 try {
     preparedStatement.setString(1, ssn);
     ResultSet rset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

 if (rset.next()) { 
          String lastName = rset.getString(1); 
          String mi = rset.getString(2); 
          String firstName = rset.getString(3); 
          String title = rset.getString(4); 
          String grade = rset.getString(5); 

          lblStatus.setText(firstName + " " + mi + 
 " " + lastName + "'s grade on course " + title + " is " + 
            grade); 
        } else { 
          lblStatus.setText("Not found"); 
        } 
      } 
 catch (SQLException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `if` which is getting executed only once and therefore, you are getting only one record.

Replace

```
if (rset.next()) { 
    String lastName = rset.getString(1); 
    String mi = rset.getString(2); 
    String firstName = rset.getString(3); 
    String title = rset.getString(4); 
    String grade = rset.getString(5); 

    lblStatus.setText(firstName + " " + mi + 
    " " + lastName + "'s grade on course " + title + " is " + 
    grade); 
} else { 
    lblStatus.setText("Not found"); 
}
```

with

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
int c = 0;
while (rset.next()) { 
    String lastName = rset.getString(1); 
    String mi = rset.getString(2); 
    String firstName = rset.getString(3); 
    String title = rset.getString(4); 
    String grade = rset.getString(5); 
    s.append(firstName).append(" ").append(mi).append(" ").append(lastName).append("'s grade on course ").append(title).append(" is ").append(grade).append("\n");     
    c++;
}
if(c>0) {
    lblStatus.setText(s.toString());
} else {
    lblStatus.setText("Not found");
}
```

Note that using `while`, you create a loop which will keep iterating until the condition, `rset.next()` remains `true` i.e. until the resultset has more elements.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the advice. I did the replacement, as you suggested, but it still displayed only one grade. The only difference being it moved on to the second grade in the database and outputted that rather than the first one.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope, it works for you. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Comment: I replaced and checked it out. It displays all the grades which is wonderful! Only minor "downside" is that it is outputted as one long line

Comment: Great! What have you used in the last `.append`? `.append("<br>") or `.append("\n")` ? Switch it to the other one and this problem will be solved.

Comment: It worked with \n. Thank you so much Arvind, you do not comprehend how much weight you just pushed off my shoulders. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (rset.next()) {
```

to

```
while (rset.next()) {
```

You will also need to get rid of this bit:

```
    } else { 
      lblStatus.setText("Not found");
```

If you want to have that message then you'll need to count how many rows you process in the `while` loop, or have a boolean flag that you set to true once you've seen a row; then test that after the loop has completed, and print the message if the flag is still false.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the else statement. I tried what you said regarding the replacement, but the output still displayed only one grade. What did change, though, was that it moved on to the second grade and displayed that rather than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add a worded explanation for the other answers you got, to let you know what the difference was. When you asked 'if it had a next' ... it said yes, executed the if block ... once ... and then moved on. It wasn't a loop. It just said ... yes, I have a next.

The while ... is a loop. That will keep executing the code block of the while, in a loop, until there are no more nexts. All your if is asking is if it had at least one. You did, so it gave you your 'one' you asked for, and moved on.

That's why we use a while loop to read a whole result set from a db.

while (rs.next() ) {
...
}

if ... isn't a loop. It does one, if there is a next, and then just moves on.

while ... is a loop. It will loop until there are no more next's.

I hope that helps you understand the logic application difference between an if and a while. We use a while to process all of the next's, because it's a loop that will repeat while the condition is true. The if just says ... yes I have a next ... does it's block once (or not) and then moves away. That's why you needed a while instead.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation! Loops were never my strong suite and this does help further instead the logic regarding the use of if and while.

Comment: And I appreciate that feedback. Sometimes I find it a good exercise to place the logic out in human language instead of always just placing out the copy paste code. Good exercise for me, and the person still has to go away and code. Unless it would take a book, and then ... I just lay down the eight lines of code. Thanks! :)